# Zend 3, developer-tools not loading

Tags: zend-framework

In a fresh skeleton application, I have problems that the developer-tool-bar is not shown. It looks like the `config/autoload/zenddevelopertools.local.php` is not loaded. I put an `echo "hello"` there that is not shown and even when I add parsing-errors to the file nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. I had to activate the `development.config` by removing the .dist

`config/development.config.php.dist` --> `config/development.config.php`